# How can you bring over junction object fields on a child of it's master-detail object?

Tags: junction-object

I have object A and object B set up as a many to many via junction object C. I want junction object C to appear on Object A's Child. Is this possible? I have tried searching online but I seem to only find answers for showing A on B or A on C. 
Is this possible to do without Custom code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you look in the "Related Lists" of the layout of object A or object B you should see object C and be able to add it. Object C is a child of both object A and object B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Junction object should already be a child of both Parent objects as it is the detail part of the relationship.....

You can use formula fields to bring over fields from either parent to the junction object and thus display those fields on either parent...

for example

Account -> JUNCTION OBJ <- Opportunity

Junction defines the relationship between the Account and the Opportunity.